# Brew cask. Hold Skype update

Tags: homebrew, skype

You know new Skype even for Mac is written on Electron and working slow. But old native version is still working.

Unfortunately `brew cu -a` https://github.com/buo/homebrew-cask-upgrade updates it to new one. Is it possible to hold version of this package (disable update) like `aptitude hold package` in debian?

Comment: It's been almost 3-years now, so I am asking again. Is pinning (pin) available with casks in brew?

Answer (score 1):

The homebrew syntax would be "brew pin skype", unfortunately, there is no "pinning" in "brew cask" - so, no.

Comment: It is very sad.

Comment: True. sudo chmod ugo-w /Applications/Skype.app ;)